# Not able to start program on boot up in linux

Tags: linux

I am not able to start a program normally on boot up of the device.
I have created a script and put that script in `/etc/init.d/S77Hello.sh`
In this script I started the program, that works as watchdog for other programs.
But after boot completion only watch dog programs runs not the other programs that should started by the watchdog program.

Interestingly when I start program using following command:
`/etc/init.d/S77Hello.sh start`
It starts all the other programs in a normal way.

S77Hello.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/mywatchdog
```

Any help to resolve the issue will be helpful.

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: Could you please post content of `S77Hello.sh` file?

Comment: Its simple script having command `/usr/local/bin/mywatchdog` thats it.

Comment: Your script runs your program in foreground.  Is `/usr/local/bin/mywatchdog` program smart enough to go into background after it is started?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's starting the watchdog itself? If so, is it possible the programs it's supposed to start depend on services that may not be available yet at the point in the boot sequence the watchdog is being started?

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov yes it is a daemon

Comment: @Cairnarvon if I run those programs in the scripts itself, then those are able to run.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Are those programs able to run *at the time the watchdog is started in the boot sequence*? Is it possible they, for example, depend on networking and networking hasn't been configured yet? Are you managing boot dependencies properly in the header?

Comment: @Cairnarvon no they are not dependent on any of other system services, if that was scenario then those programs won't start from S77Hello.sh directly.. I guess so

Comment: Then, are you absolutely sure your watchdog program is being started? That is, did you actually tell your init system to invoke your script on boot (through `update-rc.d` or whatever)? Just putting the script in `/etc/init.d` isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in `/etc/init.d` aren't automatically invoked on start-up; you have to tell your init system to do so first. If your distro has an `/etc/init.d` that's probably done through `update-rc.d`. Specifically:

```
update-rc.d S77Hello.sh defaults
```

Review the relevant man page. If you prefer a GUI, `rcconf` provides a more user-friendly interface, though you'll likely need to install that first.

Before you do that, though, fix your init script; it lacks important information. You'll probably want to read [this](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) if you haven't already.

At the very least, it need to look something like this:

```
#/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mywatchdog
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start watchdog at boot time
# Description:       Something something something
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
    start)
        /usr/local/bin/mywatchdog
        echo $! >/var/run/mywatchdog.pid
            echo "watchdog started."
        ;;
    stop)
        if kill "$(cat /var/run/mywatchdog.pid)"; then
            rm /var/run/mywatchdog.pid
            echo "watchdog stopped."
        else
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

This assumes a Debian-like system to some extent, but since you're using a distro with a sysvinit on ARM, I'm guessing you're using Raspian on the Raspberry Pi. If not, review how existing init scripts work in your distro.